# Laravel error: View::__toString() must not throw an exception

Tags: laravel, view, routes

I have a problem to loop GET data from URL.
My array looks like after var dump :

```
array(5) {
[0]=>
array(5) {
  ["sku"]=>
  string(9) "AH1172164"
  ["name"]=>
  string(21) "dasdas"
  ["url"]=>
  string(42) "21321312"
  ["price"]=>
  string(6) "866.00"
  ["stocks"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["partner"]=>
      string(6) "321312"
      ["qty"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["spotted"]=>
      string(14) "1 month "
    }
  }
}
```

My code for looping the data in blade file:

```
@php 
    $d=$_GET['Api'];
    var_dump($d);

    foreach($d as $value)
    {
        echo $value;
    
    }
@endphp
```

When I use `var_dump` the data are  listed correctly but when I want to loop the variable `$d` I got this error:

> Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException: Array to string conversion (View: F:\xampp\htdocs\semafor-master\resources\views\platform\tools\

I have API.. and my controller   for this :

```
public function gen(Request $request)
{
    // Some queries, and loops to fill $data variable..
    return \Redirect::route('platform.tools.gen', ['Api'=>$data]);
    
}
```

I can't use return view, I must use return redirect because after API REQUEST I want to redirect to this route.
The  gen view  is Orchid admin panel screen.
What can be the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your data should be available in a variable called `$Api` in the `gen` page. What happens when you run `{{ dd($Api) }}` this in the blade file?

Comment: @thursday_dan I got a same error..

Comment: Try to decode your data before the loop with `$d=json_decode($_GET['Api']);`

Comment: @luca_999 Same error.. :/

Comment: @luca_999 
I have problem with my array loop... 
I edited the question please  check !

Answer (score 1):

Part of the answer is that somewhere in the stack, there's a call to a magic `__toString()` method. Exceptions being called therein is only allowable in Php 7.4 and up. Try wrapping your behavior in a generic try/catch and make it dump the message from the Exception that it's trying to throw. The message you're seeing now is just a symptom of a different problem.

Comment: I checked and the error is :  Array to string conversion

Comment: This is my array:

array(5) {
    [0]=>
    array(5) {
      ["sku"]=>
      string(9) "AH1172164"
      ["name"]=>
      string(21) "dasdas"
      ["url"]=>
      string(42) "21321312"
      ["price"]=>
      string(6) "866.00"
      ["stocks"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        array(3) {
          ["partner"]=>
          string(6) "321312"
          ["qty"]=>
          string(1) "1"
          ["spotted"]=>
          string(14) "1 month "
        }
      }
    }

Comment: Might be your 'stocks' value. Looks like you're trying to echo the nested array, it's throwing an error, then it's throwing a different error about its inability to throw the first one.

Comment: Yes... How I can loop the  whole array?

Comment: Just add some logit preempting your `echo` statement checking for `if (is_array($value)) { ...`. By the way, you might want to consider using [Blade Directives](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#blade-directives) instead of raw Php in your templates, it's just a little cleaner in that context.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an array of array variable, so you should encode your value to a string before printing it:

```
@php 
    $d=$_GET['Api'];

    foreach($d as $value)
    {
        echo json_encode($value);
    
    }
@endphp
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a good solution but  when I  print , the data are in brackets : "AH1008274" like this.. Why?

Comment: Because you are encoding an array into standard JSON format, if you want to access or print `$value` properties you should refer to them directly with `$value["sku"]`, ...

Comment: Yes I print this way.. $value['sku']; but there is still  in quotation mark